# Stream/River depth GIS shapefile for contiguous United State

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

I am looking for a shapefile of stream/river depth for the contiguous United States for my GIS project. NHD does not provide depth information. Could you please recommend me any suggestions?

Comment: you mean bathymetry/contours data?

Comment: No, I mean the shapefile which tells the depth of the river in different section of the river. I do not think the contour data would help to tell any info about rivers

Comment: ben, i'm not 100%, but pretty sure what you seek is here. posting as comment since i don't know 100% what you want...if the data is here, it is not in one shapefile; you're going to have to cobble one together from multiple sources of depth data here. https://water.usgs.gov/lookup/getgislist

Comment: Thanks Albert for the info. I think, I need more than one sources for the depth data. Lets see how far I can go and it makes it difficult for me because I need that information for rivers in different parts of the United States.

Comment: Did you end up having luck cobbling from USGS?